# How to print all parameters passed in stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which takes a parameter of `varchar(max)` type. My users should able to pass a single parameter as well as multiple parameters (separated by comma). My stored procedure should print the single value if single parameter is passed or print multiple values if multiple parameters are passed.

For example my procedure name is `sp_printvalue`. So if I execute this procedure with single parameter

```
exec sp_printvalue A
```

it should print A and if I execute it with multiple paramaters

```
exec sp_printvalue A,B,C,D
```

it should print all values A B C D.

Please help me to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an xml parameter and then read it using the node method. Here's an example

```
create procedure usp_PrintValue
@param xml
as
set nocount on;

declare @result varchar(100)

select
    @result = coalesce(@result + ', ', '') + tab.col.value('@Value', 'char(1)')
from @param.nodes('/Parameter') as tab(col)

print @result
go
```

And execution

```
declare @a xml

set @a = N'
    <Parameter Value="A"/>
    <Parameter Value="B"/>
    <Parameter Value="C"/>
    <Parameter Value="D"/>
'

exec usp_PrintValue @a
```